# VIM: how to set the window size of quickfix window?

Tags: dictionary, vim, window, size

I've set hotkey for opening quickfix window in my ~/.vimrc like this:

```
map <F9> vertical botright copen
```

(1) It works, But the window size is too narrow, how can I set the qfix window size to 60 within the same "map" statement? I don't wish to type extra commands after

(2) If I open it horizontally like

```
map <F10> copen
```

By default the quickfix window is 10 lines in hightly. How to set this size to 40, within the same "map" statement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with these mappings:

```
noremap <F9>  :execute "vertical botright copen \| vertical resize 60"<cr>
noremap <F10> :execute "copen \| resize 40"<cr>
```

**Edit:**

As [@romaini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) stated in comment you still can achieve that **effectively** via:

```
noremap <F9> :vertical botright copen 60<cr>
noremap <F10> :copen 40<cr>
```

---

See `:help copen`

Comment: * useless use of `:execute` and * `:40copen`

Comment: Side effects of being night owl but still can be useful `execute` command.